# How to use a numpy array with fromiter

Tags: numpy

I tried to use a numpy array with fromiter but It gave this error

```
import numpy
l=numpy.dtype([("Ad","S20"),("Yas","i4"),("Derecelendirme","f")])
a=numpy.array([("Dr.Wah",20,0.9)])
d=numpy.fromiter(a,dtype=l,count=3)
print(d)
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Why not just declare `a` with `dtype=l`?  Otherwise your float values will get coerced to strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [172]: dt=np.dtype([("Ad","S20"),("Yas","i4"),("Derecelendirme","f")]) 
     ...: alist = [("Dr.Wah",20,0.9)]
```

The normal way to define a structured array is to use a list of tuples for the data along with the dtype:

```
In [173]: np.array( alist, dtype=dt)                                                                         
Out[173]: 
array([(b'Dr.Wah', 20, 0.9)],
      dtype=[('Ad', 'S20'), ('Yas', '<i4'), ('Derecelendirme', '<f4')])
```

`fromiter` works as well, but isn't as common

```
In [174]: np.fromiter( alist, dtype=dt)                                                                      
Out[174]: 
array([(b'Dr.Wah', 20, 0.9)],
      dtype=[('Ad', 'S20'), ('Yas', '<i4'), ('Derecelendirme', '<f4')])
```

If you create an array without the dtype:

```
In [175]: a = np.array(alist)                                                                                
In [176]: a                                                                                                  
Out[176]: array([['Dr.Wah', '20', '0.9']], dtype='<U6')
In [177]: _.shape                                                                                            
Out[177]: (1, 3)
```

`a.astype(dt)` does not work.  You have to use a recfunction:

```
In [179]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                                                
In [180]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(a, dtype=dt)                                                         
Out[180]: 
array([(b'Dr.Wah', 20, 0.9)],
      dtype=[('Ad', 'S20'), ('Yas', '<i4'), ('Derecelendirme', '<f4')])
```